# Is there a way to edit/remove url filenames(especially .html extensions) from website url without access to the server?

Tags: html, web, server, hosting

I have a website that is hosted on my university's servers.

The URL shows up like

> website.com/index.html

I would highly prefer it to show like:

> website.com

Or at least like:

> website.com/index

Is there a way of manipulating how the URL shows up without changing server properties?

This also applies to URLs like "website.com/about.html", I would prefer them to be like "website.com/about".

Comment: Without modifying anything in the server?  So where are you going to modify it? You can install/create an extension for your browser, but it would only work on your device. Otherwise, with access to the server, you can set up the URL rewriting rules.

Comment: So it isn't possible to change it through code or similar in the files themselves?

Comment: Use browser extension like `TamperMonkey` to add javascript and change the url shows up in the address bar.

Comment: If you're talking about the code that lives in the server, you can create a controller that passes the request (eg, GET /index returns index.html), this assumes the site isn't just bunch of static html

Answer (score 0):

you need to add another directory into your file structure on your page and the main index.html will stay at the highest level, usually this is done with the assets directory or any subpages. Give it a shot it worked on my own site i hosted.

go to your public html directory where your index.html file is then create an assets directory or anything else. and it should end the main page with just the .com

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're saying. Currently the files are located in Desktop/Project/index.html;Desktop/Project/about.html etc. How should i try and change this exactly? Can you provide an example?

Comment: ok so in your public html directory you have your index.html file then just create a new directory in that same file path. so i have my index.html and my other html pages but all of my css and js files and libraries are ina directory assets at this same level.